# Grant SELECT to all existing and future tables except views in a database on a MySQL RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, view, amazon-rds, database-administration, user-permissions

I have a MySQL database test with 10 tables and 5 views.
I want to give access to all the current 10 tables and any future tables that will be added. I don't want to give access to any of the 5 views in the database.
If I do this:

```
GRANT SELECT 
ON test.* 
TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

This does the trick but it also gives access to the views which I don't want.

I can also do :

```
SELECT CONCAT("GRANT SELECT ON test.", table_name, " TO 'view_test'@'%';")
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE table_schema = "test" AND table_type <> "VIEW"
```

But this will generate grants for only existing tables. But this way I will have to explicitly grant select access on any future tables which I don't want.

So, my end goal is to grant Select on all existing and future tables but no access to the views.
Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL

Comment: That's a good question. I would guess it might be possible if you use your first GRANT statement, then create the view tables using definer = user, and sql security invoker|definer syntaxes. Because in the documentation it says those are able to limit the access permissions of a user to the view tables. But I haven't figured out how to get it working in my own tests yet.

Comment: Have you tried granting permission on whole db and then revoking permission on views.

    GRANT SELECT ON `YOURDATABASE`.* TO 'user'@'%'
    
    REVOKE SHOW VIEW ON `YOURDATABASE`.* TO 'user'@'%'